# Numeric grouping variable in rCharts NVD3

Tags: nvd3.js, rcharts

I'm writing a chart in rCharts using NVD3. Whatever class of variable I feed into the group column, it takes the order of as.character. For example, if I feed in either time (2013-11-03; 2013-11-10), or forced numeric dates (11.3, 11.10...) the order is not preserved. Can I add something in the x-axis similar to the xAxis='ordinal' call in xPlot?

```
nPlot.PH <- nPlot(n_total ~ name, group="ds.nv", data=btl.data, 
                type="multiBarChart")
nPlot.PH$show(cdn=T)
```

n_total is a count, by name (region) for dates (ds.nv is formatted as numeric).

Comment: It looks like I either need to create the JSON myself, or adjust the [toJSONArray2](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/dev/R/toJSON.R) function to sort on the x variable and the group within...

Comment: If you are dealing with dates, you can convert them into milliseconds and they will be picked up correctly. If you post some sample data, we should be able to help.

Comment: Ahha! Yes, it converts the dates, but using the dates as a grouping didn't auto-sort by date. I sorted the data in R before passing it to the function and it worked great.

Comment: Great. You can post your answer here. Avoid using variable names with dots in them, since dots have special meaning in javascript.